# Ubuntu hanging on shutdown/reboot

Tags: shutdown, 14.10, reboot

My situation is very similar to [Shutdown Hangs for 5 Minutes on Kubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461646/shutdown-hangs-for-5-minutes-on-kubuntu-14-04) but I am using 14.10 with a gnome environment instead of KDE (Ubuntu with gnome package added not the native version). That alone shouldn't be causing it as I have coworkers with same hardware and setup with no issues.

The verbose shutdown screen prints the same line

```
* Asking all remaining processes to terminate...

* All Processes ended within 300 seconds...
nm-dispatcher.action: Caught signal 15, shutting down...
* Deactivating swap...
mount: / is busy
* Will now halt
[ 486.185416] reboot: Power down
```

Unlike the original poster I don't have modem manager installed and there isn't anything outputted between nm-dispatcher and deactivating the swap for me to use as a guideline :/

If anyone knows some things to check for or a way to force a shutdown after 60 seconds of hanging vs 300 it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found a heavy-handed way to force a shutdown sooner than 300 seconds. The 300 second waiting period is specified in `/etc/init.d/sendsigs`, which is a shutdown script that attempts to kill remaining processes that have not successfully ended in previous parts of the shutdown sequence. Find the following code in the script:

```
if [ $seq -ge 300 ] ; then
   break
fi
```

This is where the 300 second maximum wait time is specified. Change 300 to a desired number of seconds greater than 10 (other parts of the script already specify a wait time of 10 seconds). You will need to use sudo to change this file, since it does not have write permissions for an ordinary user.

This is a very heavy-handed tactic, and it's not a good long-term solution. If you have network file storage which might be hanging at shutdown, or if *any* other process (ie. mySQL) might be legitimately waiting at shutdown, do not follow this method. But for a laptop or general purpose computer with a standard software configuration, it will at least allow you to shutdown and restart without waiting 5 minutes every time.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```

or try

`sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: no dice on that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Plank installed?

I had the same problem, after install the [Plank dock](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaunchpad.net%2Fplank&ei=jkySVNqSGNCwsASQloGoCQ&usg=AFQjCNHfb-oY8gQOszWqU0zSp3xN4X8yzA&sig2=Jd31NICSRGwIhr2HuCerxg&bvm=bv.82001339,d.cWc) and set it to start with the system. If that's your case. The workaround for this problem is just add a time delay to this startup program.

Go to the terminal and type:

```
cd  ~/.config/autostart/
gedit plank.desktop
```

(replace "plank" for the name of your autostart file)

Look for the follow line:

> X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true

And replace for:

> X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=13

After that, logout, login and check if it works.

See ya! ;-)

Comment: Seems reasonable, but nope no plank installed.

Comment: Try to make the same procedure to any startup program.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Kubuntu 14.10. My solution was:

1. I changed this line in file `/etc/default/grub` to look like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash init=/lib/systemd/systemd"`
2. After that, I ran `sudo update-grub` in a Terminal

Now the system shuts down again...:-)